# Check java library compatibility with GraalVM

Tags: java, graalvm

I'm studying GraalVM and I would like to try to use some library that I use in my project. 
There is some tool that can check the whole code and give me a report about code not compatible with GraalVM native image?

Thanks in advance,
Davide

Answer (score 4):

It would be hard and misleading to build a tool that works for any given JVM library without the application in which this library is used. The reason is that support of a library depends on two major things: (1) which functions in the library are used, and (2) which static initializers are executed during image generation as opposed to image runtime.

GraalVM `native-image` itself will report features that are currently not supported in all of the reachable code on the classpath. The error reporting mechanism of `native-image` should provide enough information about the unsupported features that allows the user to fix them.

`native-image` should be used in conjunction with the `native-image-configure` tool that generates configuration files necessary for configuring the `native-image` tool for a given project.